# Permission to control user accounts belonging to specific group only

Tags: django, permissions, authorization

Is it possible in django to create permission to control (view/add/delete/change) user accounts only from specific group or e. g. having flag `is_staff` set to false? How can I do it?

For example, users from 'operators' group can manage users from 'clients' group and cannot control (even view) staff user accounts in admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do that. You can specify groups of users and assign particular rights to them. It's quite well described in the docs - please see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've read the docs and I know that I can assing rights to groups. But the question was: how I can create permission to control only specific objects in the table. E.g., standard `change_user` permission allows to change ANY 'user' record. I want to restrict this to allow changing ONLY 'user' records which belong to specific group and to deny changing other 'user' records.

So, unfortunately, that did not help.

Comment: Your question started with 'Is it possible ...' and not with 'how i can create...' hence my answer :) Also please note that a specific answer on 'how to do something' can be provided only if you would share some code:) However, If I understood your question correctly I think this could be done using decorators or test which is well described in the docs under the provided link. Good luck!

Comment: The question was 'Is it possible TO CREATE (custom) PERMISSION TO CONTROL ONLY SPECIFIC USER ACCOUNTS' (e.g. belonging to special group), not 'Is it possible to assign rights to groups'. Unfortunately, you did not understand the question correctly. Good luck!